# The actionscript game

Tags: actionscript

getting these errors V:\Users\documents--Lab1_resources\start\MainTimer.as, Line 21   1120: Access of undefined property currentMin.
and 
V:\Users\documents--Lab1_resources\start\MainTimer.as, Line 31  1120: Access of undefined property onTimerComplete.

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
//import flash.events.ThrottleEvent;

public class MainTimer extends MovieClip {

    private var currentMin:int;
    private var currentSec:int;

    private var oneSecondTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    public var timerHasStopped:Boolean = false;

    public function MainTimer() {
        // constructor code
        trace("the Main Timer is here");
        currentMin = 1; 
        currentSec = 5; 

        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        if(currentSec < 10) {
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }else{
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
    }
    oneSecondTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerComplete);     
    oneSecondTimer.start();
    }

    private function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void{

        trace("TIMER HAS STARTED. COUNTING DOWN.......");           

        currentSec = currentSec - 1;
        if (currentSec < 0){
            currentSec = 59;
            currentMin = currentMin - 1;
        }
        if(currentMin < 0) {
            currentMin = 0;
            currentSec = 0;
            resetTimer();
        }

        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
        if(currentSec < 10){
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }
    }

    public function resetTimer():void{
        oneSecondTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerComplete);
        trace("TIMER HAS FINISHED. RESETTING.......");
        //update our display
        currentMin = 1;
        currentSec = 5;
        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
        //Adjust display for seconds less than 10
        if (currentSec < 10){
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }//end if
        timerHasStopped = false;
        //if the timer needs to start again, add the following line of code.
        oneSecondTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerComplete);

    }//end function
}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever actionScript compiler can't find the specified property, it flags it with compiler error 1120. 
`currentMin` and `onTimerComplete` are the name of your offending property.